# iOS Views down or upscale

Tags: ios, view, constraints

Since there are so many screen sizes now, is it better to make views in the vieweditor of xcode based on a bigger size and scale down by constraints? or is it better to make views on a smaller base and scale up by constraints?

Answer (score 0):

It is totally up to personal preference and what works best for you.
In any case I like to start small and work my way up. Running out of space is a bigger problem than having too much space.
But be sure to make use of the extra space to better the user experience and not just upscale everything.